# Why isn't my 2D bullet's collider colliding with anything?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, collision

I'm trying to make a platformer game that uses 2D sprites in 3D space. For some reason, though the bullet the player shoots fires correctly from the GO that's a child of the player, it won't collide with anything (enemies, other objects, etc.) in either 2D or 3D. I have a 3D character controller on the parent player GO, but that doesn't affect the bullet object I'm firing, does it?

Colliders on everything appropriately.
Tried with IsTrigger both on and off in various combinations.
Objects are on the same layer and the same Z axis position.

```
//BULLET FIRING SCRIPT

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2") && !Input.GetButton("Fire3") && 
        Time.time > nextFireTime)

   {
        Rigidbody2D cloneRb = Instantiate(bullet,  
 bulletSpawn.position, Quaternion.identity) as Rigidbody2D;
        cloneRb.AddForce(bulletPrefab.transform.right *  
 projectileForce);
        nextFireTime = Time.time + fireRate;

    }

}


//____________________________________________________________

//BULLET OBJECT SCRIPT

private void Start()
{
    direction = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

    if (direction == -1)
    {
        facingLeft = true;
    }
    else if (direction == 1)
    {
        facingLeft = false;
    }

    else if (direction == 0)
    {
        facingLeft = false;
    }


    if (facingLeft == false)
    {
        rb.velocity = transform.right * speed;
        Debug.Log("Fired Bullet");
    }
    else
    {
        bulletPrefab.transform.Rotate(0, 180, 0);
        firePoint.transform.Rotate(0, 180, 0);
        Debug.Log("Rotated Bullet");
        Debug.Log("Fired Bullet Left");
        rb.velocity = transform.right * speed;

    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}


public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)

     {
       Debug.Log("Bullet Hit:");
       Debug.Log(collider.name);
       Enemy enemy = collider.GetComponent<Enemy>();
       if (enemy != null)
          {
            enemy.TakeDamage(damage);
          }
       Destroy(gameObject);
      }
```

Expected Result: Bullet object collides with other objects, prints Debug.Log output and gets destroyed.

Actual Result: Bullet object fires through, in front of, or behind other objects that also have colliders and there is no Debug.Log output. Bullet does not get destroyed and so instantiates clones infinitely when assigned input is entered.

Comment: First of all; 2d physics will not work with 3d physics. Secondly, make sure you have a rigidbody on one of the objects that are colliding

Comment: Ok so the bullet seems to have a 2d rigid body do you have a trigger or collider on the  enemy??  sadly this seems such a common issue

Comment: @FredrikSchön But the bullet object and what it's colliding with are all 2D...and I do have a rigidbody on the bullet and have tried with and without them on the objects that are colliding.

Comment: @BugFinder I've tried with and without triggers on the bullet and the enemy, and both.

Comment: Is it a Rigidbody2D?

Comment: there isnt really enough info here to properly help.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed issue by checking Default/Default in the Layer Collision Matrix under Edit-->Project Settings-->Physics. Not sure if it's supposed to be checked by default and somehow got unchecked but checking it solved the problem.